# How can you pin a frequently used file on an FTP site in Excel 2016

Tags: ftp, microsoft-excel-2016, pinning

There is a file that I refer to frequently on an FTP site that I once managed to pin to the Recent files in the Open menu of Excel 2016.  I can't save the file on the FTP, so it will not add to the recently used files list to allow selecting it to pin.  I know it can be done, just can't figure out how I did.

I've been moved to a new computer and want to remake the pin rather than downloading a copy, because the file is updated regularly.  This is Excel 2016 in Office 365 ProPlus on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the direct link to the file, you can add the hyperlink into a blank excel and name that excel and then pin that excel. This way, when you click on the hyperlink it will open or download the file from the ftp.

That's the best I can come up with. If you're not allowed to download the excel, this way you can open the most up to date excel with the quick pinned hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Windows 10 with 64 bit MS Office.

Add the FTP site as a network location.  In File Explorer, right-click “Computer”, select “Add a network location”, enter the FTP address like ftp://ftp.microsoft.com, select “Log on anonymously” (or enter a username and password).

In File Explorer, open the new FTP network location.  Open the Excel file you want to pin. If necessary to select Excel to open the file, specify the location of EXCEL.EXE. (In my case, 64 bit Excel, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16.) The file should open in Excel.

If you want to pin the FTP file in Excel under Pinned, select File>Open. The file should show in the recently opened list. Pin it there.

If you want to pin the FTP file to the Task bar, right click the Excel icon on the Task bar (assuming you have already pinned Excel), right click the FTP file under “Recent” and “Pin to this list”. You can now open the file from the Task Bar.